# Tips for making a lightweight windows ami for running on the t1.micro instance

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2

I'd like to pare down windows 2008 server as much as possible and was looking for ideas. I've got it running ok on the t1.micro instance, but I'd like to give as many resources as I can to my custom service.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install Windows Server 2008 core?  Many people overlook this as a possibility.

Comment: Mike - the AMI machines are prebuilt by Amazon or others, for ease of use. It does not appear that they have a Core AMI.

Comment: In US East (Virginia), check out AMI ami-7cb91d15.  It is Win2008 R2 Core 64-bit.

Comment: Not knowing a lot about AMI, I just browsed the AMIs available from MS directly. I didn't even scroll down to see the community-shared AMIs. I do indeed see that there are a few Core images.